# How to hide "Showing 1 of N Entries" with the dataTables.js library

Tags: javascript, datatables

How do you remove the "Showing 1 of N entries" line of text on a dataTable (that is when using the javascript library dataTables? I think I was looking for something along these lines...

```
 $('#example').dataTable({
      "showNEntries" : false
       });
```

Pretty sure this is a simple one, but cannot seem to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You can remove it with the `bInfo` option (http://datatables.net/usage/features#bInfo)

```
   $('#example').dataTable({
       "bInfo" : false
   });
```

**Update:**
Since Datatables 1.10.* this option can be used as `info`, `bInfo` still works in current nightly build (1.10.10).

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, if all you want to do is hide it.  If you need to style it, its nice that Allan has wrapped each element in it's own class so you can get at it.

Comment: I like this answer best too because it keeps it directed to the dataTable params but thanks Daiku too as I have some choice...Nick

Comment: This makes the "editable" table type break (impossible to edit or save rows).

Comment: @jovan I don't think this option can interfere with "editable". Do you have an example (jsfiddle maybe) I can look into it for you?

Comment: @BMH I got it to work - to be honest, I don't even remember what the problem was any more!

Comment: After set ```info: false```, there is still a ```<div class="col-sm-5"></div>``` element before the div that contains the pagination links.

Comment: in R, with the DT library it can be done with the following code:

 datatable(the_data,options(bInfo = FALSE))

Answer (score 23):

try this for **hide**

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
  "info": false
});
```

and try this **for change label**

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
 "oLanguage": {
               "sInfo" : "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",// text you want show for info section
            },

});
```

Answer (score 11):

If you also need to **disable the drop-down** (not to hide the text) then set the `lengthChange` option to `false`

```
$('#datatable').dataTable( {
  "lengthChange": false
} );
```

Works for DataTables 1.10+

Read more in the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange)

Comment: This hides the drop down.  It does not hide the text "showing 1 of N entries"

Answer (score 6):

**Now**, this seems to work:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "info": false
});
```

it hides that `div`, altogether

Answer (score 0):

It is Work for me:

```
language:{"infoEmpty": "No records available",}
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, which asks for a way to suppress the message when there _are_ records. Looks like you are changing the message to be shown with there are no records, which is not the problem that OP is asking about.