# DataTable : How to hide "Showing # to # of # entries (filtered from # total entries)"?

Tags: datatables

I am using [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/) on my application.

I want to hide the detail in the bottom left, how do I do that ?

*"Showing 1 to 10 of 1,657 entries (filtered from 9,044 total entries)"*

Here is my settings :

```
$('#inventory_related').dataTable({

    "lengthMenu": [ 10 ] ,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "searchHighlight": true


  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide "Showing 1 of N Entries" with the dataTables.js library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438226/how-to-hide-showing-1-of-n-entries-with-the-datatables-js-library)

Answer (score 4):

Newer version of the DataTable now uses `"info" : false` as opposed to the previous `"bInfo" : false`

Answer (score 3):

$('#tbl-my-queue').DataTable( {
                         "language": {
                                   "infoFiltered": ""
                               },
                        });

Add infoFiltered option as blank

Answer (score 2):

Add this to my setting `"bInfo" : false`.

Final Setting should look like this :

```
 $('#inventory_related').dataTable({

    "lengthMenu": [ 10 ] ,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "searchHighlight": true,
    "bInfo" : false

  });
```